# Statically caching arbitrary HREFs in HTML

Tags: html, binary, base64, dereference, data-uri

If a `href` contains a URI, which is basically a *pointer* to an arbitrary resource / data (images, fonts, what have you), wouldn't it make sense to allow a developer to localize some of this data, maybe in HTML? Here's what I had in mind:

```
<body>
  <head>
    <!-- ... -->
    <meta url="foo.com/someUrlToMask" data="base64 encoded data">
    <!-- ... -->
  </head>
```

There's a style attribute `data:` in [CSS3](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/data_URIs) that lets us sorta-kinda do this, except for the masking part. It would be crucially useful for offline development, for instance, where you might be using a library like Twitter bootstrap, and twitter makes a request to Google for a specific font. How would you localize that data, for instance? The only hope you have for developing offline is if your browser decides to cache that `.tff` file or image.

The only issue that comes to mind is if some malicious HTML developer decides to embed / mask their own malicious version of some resource, say js-nacl for instance. Then the HTML developer could use their version to do haneous things, without the javascript / css developer's consent. In this light (with masking forbidden), a URI is the *identifier* for a resource, not an arbitrary reference to one.

> Given that the HTML developer is the "master" developer, i.e. the last
>   point of development before shipment, I'd argue that masking is power
>   that the HTML developer deserves and should be allowed to use; just as
>   an HTML developer could overwrite a global JavaScript variable:

```
<head>
  <script href="jquery"></script>
  <script>
    window.JQuery = myMaliciousJQuery;
  </script>
</head>
```

> Therefore, masking URIs is **just as unsafe** as the existence of
>   global variables are in JavaScript.

## Conclusion

Why isn't there a method to mask a URI with localized binary data, in HTML?

---

### Glossary

- localize: to store locally, i.e.

  - `<script href="foo.com/foo.js"></script>` vs.
    `<script>// all of foo.js's text</script>`
  - `<link href="foo.com/foo.css" rel="stylesheet">` vs.
    `<style>/* all of foo.css's text */</style>`
- mask: to override a reference to data, i.e.

  - how DNS servers work
  - how resolv.conf works
  - how browser caches work
  - how any caching system works :)

Comment: This isn't really a question. It's a proposal. We can't answer those.

Comment: The conclusion has the final "question"! :)

Comment: Your "question" is essentially, "why hasn't my proposal been implemented?". And the answer is "because you're proposing it in the wrong place -- in a question on Stack Overflow".

Comment: My "proposal" is just a gimmick at an idea for the solution, I don't actually know if this exists or not

Comment: Right. And my point is, this isn't the kind of "question" Stack Overflow is for. Please read "[What types of questions should I avoid asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)".